# Deleted NSManagedObject stays in memory even after deletion

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am having few issues on iPad app, related to CoreData.
This time regarding deleting of object. 
Looking at instruments (allocation template) I found that my deleted object stays in memory forever, or at least 7hours, the time I left instruments on. Also the leak instruments doesn't show anything about.

I double check, after saving the context, both the table view which is not displaying the object among its row, and the database itself, that has physically a missing row.

I am not able, with instruments, to tell who is keeping a reference to it, preventing the object to be deallocated.

I am using ARC, and an NSFetchedResultsController is managing the UITableView.

Do you have any guess, or suggestion about what instruments to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about that. If you try to access the object, core data will give you an exception telling you it couldn't fulfill a fault for that object. The object is gone from your application's database. Core data's internal work might keep a reference to it for other purposes, but that purpose is out of your control.